# How to change the URL of a Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, urlrewriter

I need to modify the URL of a visualforce page so that it is represented with the record name instead of the record ID.

The VF page would just hold the `apex:detail` tag and use a standard controller for my custom object.

Here’s and example of what I need:

Standard VF Page url : `..../pageName?id=a27fhe1883`

What I need: `...../pageName?objectName=Name of object`

Each object name will be unique so duplicates shouldn’t be a problem.

I’ve researched and I have seen how to url rewrite with sites but this would be a stand alone page. Is this possible without using sites?

Comment: Object name... or Record name? Using the name field in most cases is fragile and highly not recommended. Is this just to make the URL a bit more human readable?

Comment: Also, not a full answer but the standard controller must use a record id. A custom controller or an extension can leverage any value you decide to embed in the URL.

Comment: Sorry, I meant record name, and do you know do May documentation or other posts where this has been achieved?

Comment: What is your use case here? Why do you want a record name in the URL? Also how is your VF page getting initialized, is it from a click of a button, etc.?

Comment: @Jayant Das There is a current system that needs the url represented that way. The people running that system have a url and then append the code (like P1234) to the end of the url. It would be a long and tedious process if they would have to change anything other than the first half of the url. They just need to access this VF page from an external link

Comment: So if I understand this, the external system is more concerned on how they can pass the code to the VF page rather than its actual representation, and as long as your custom controller can process what was passed by the external system, then there's no real concern on how the URL is formed. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @Jayant Das Let me explain this better. There is an external system that uses a certain url and has a php script that runs and appends a code to the back of the url. Example: the url before: www.example.com the url after php script www.example.com/code=1234. They are just wanting to change www.example.com to the Salesforce url and keep the same script. So my VF page should have the url for that page but use the code (which is the record name and is unique)  instead of the ID for a record

Comment: So ultimately you want to capture the *code* value sent by the external system to your VF page while using standard controller, right? And that the external system will call your VF page as myinstance.salesforce.com/yourVFPage?codeName=XYZ

Comment: @Jayant Das Nothing really needs to be captured or sent. I basically I want them to be able to use  myinstance.salesforce.come/yourVFPage?codeName=XYZ to reach a detail page for that specific code. For example, the VF page should show the detail info for code XYZ and have that url so that the user can click their link in the external system and take them to my page.

Comment: So as long as your VF page's URL is configured at external site as *myinstance.salesforce.com/yourVFPage?codeName=XYZ*, and that you are able to display the details based on XYZ, you really need not do anything else here. When the external site redirects to your VF page, that is what you will see as URL. Are you additionally looking for directions as how your VF page will utilize the code to display details?

Comment: No I was asking if customizing the url can be done without creating a site. I’ve seen posts about url rewrite but I didn’t want to make a separate external site for this situation.

Comment: If the external user isn't logged in, you'll need an externally available site anyway, and if you're writing your own page, you can basically do anything you want with your url parameters. You really don't need to customize your urls.

Comment: The users of the external site will have access to Salesforce so they will be able to reach the Visualforce page without the site.  @battery.cord

Comment: I still think the best solution for you would be to set up a page to redirect using the `action` parameter to the standard page by finding the id of the given record by the name provided in the url. I'll make an edit to my answer in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do both? If each system is only looking for a single parameter, providing both makes sense, and doesn't break anything.

There's a few places you can do this:

1. Using javascript when you load your page
2. <strike>In your controller</strike>
3. <strike>In your `action` attribute of your page</strike>

Changing the current page reference in apex code doesn't seem to affect the page, and I wasn't able to find anyone else who was able to do it, so I'm chalking that one up to a failure.

However, you can use javascript to modify your page parameters on the fly:

```
<script>
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href + '&objectName={!RecordName}');    
</script>
```

Since this is javascript, and you're worrying about calling from an external system which might not run the needed code on the page to change the parameter, I'd also recommend looking into doing something like setting up a first page to redirect to the right page, based on the given values. Set the `action` of the page to return a `PageReference` based on an id provided, and add the record name to the returned url.

Basically, no matter what, you're probably also going to need the id of a given record.

Things you'll still have to worry about including encoding the name to not break urls, spaces, etc. Junk in your record names could pollute the Url so we need to escape any characters which would break a url (`/,&?$\`).

---

If you're using your own visualforce page, you can set up anything as a url parameter to identify a record, as long as its unique & queryable. Take a look at the example below. It grabs the record name from the url (or reports an error), and the `record` variable uses the name to query for a certain record. You could even redirect to a standard page once you find the id of the record if you wanted to avoid writing code to render the details.

```
public class DummyClass {

    public String RecordName { get; set; }

    public sObject record { 
        get {
            if (record == null && RecordName != null) {
                record = [
                    SELECT Id, Name
                    FROM Account 
                    WHERE Name = :RecordName
                    LIMIT 1
                ];
            }

            return record; 
        } 
        set;
    }

    public DummyClass() {
        if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().containsKey('RecordName')) {
            RecordName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordName'); 
        } else {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'No name provided ..'));
        }
    }

    public PageReference RedirectToStandardPage() {
        if (record != null) {
            return new PageReference('/' + record.Id); 
        } else {
            return null; // Need some kind of error handling, this will cause an infinite loop 
        }
    }

}
```

Your page will look like this:

```
<apex:page controller="DummyClass" action="{!RedirectToStandardPage}" >
    <Apex:pageMessages />
</apex:page>
```

You'll need some error handling (probably better to call a redirect using JS on the page so you can show the error message), but this should serve as a good example.